# No Answering: prevent answering questions

Tags: script, answers

Do you answer too many questions on stack sites?  Does answering questions put you into a cycle of debating with people you'd rather not be spending time on?  Then this app is for you.

It does one thing, but it does it well: it hides the Answer form on Question pages, making it difficult but not impossible to answer questions.

For more on why I wrote it, see [How to not get reputation points on Stack Overflow](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201102/how_to_not_get_reputation_points_on_stack_overflow.html).

The script is a simple Greasemonkey script: [no_so_answers.user.js](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/misc/no_so_answers.user.js)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           No answering on Stackoverflow
// @namespace      http://nedbatchelder.com/greasemonkey
// @description    Hide the answer box on Stack Overflow 
//                 to stop obsessive behavior
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(
    "@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml); " +
    ".question-page #post-form { display: none; }"
    );
```